# Playstore multiple apk

Tags: android, google-play

My android app contains a c++ library and the apk is kind of large, as it contains all the c++ abi builds. So I decided to publish to the Playstore multiple apks. If in the future change my mind and decide to upload a universal apk will that work or I need to create a new listing?

Answer (score 1):

Playstore handles it.

I have done it. And it works perfectly.

No need to worry about these things.

Answer (score 0):

In new Play store developer console if you want to add multiple APK than you must need to use **same package name** and **same keystore key** but **different version code**. You have publish app then first upload Apk e.g mobile_release and rollout for production, after when you upload another apk, you should choose option RETAIN on previous APK also with current APK.